# jquery object, how to apply top level value to children?

Tags: javascript

hi i am updating the keyIndex array, which is created in object, while i add the array to URL it's not work:

my code :

```
var dataObject = {
    Indices: {
        subIndex: {
            keyIndex: [], //this is not updating in baseURL 'keyIndex'
            method: 'GetCCINationalIndicesData',
            baseURL: 'http://107.20.173.235/BlufinAPI/Service/ConsumerConfidenceIndex.svc/GetCCINationalIndicesData?InputJSON={"IndexID":"' + keyIndex + '","FromMonth":"10","FromYear":"2011","ToMonth":"3","ToYear":"2012"}'
        }
    },
    Geography: {
        0: '1',
        tiers: {
            method: 'GetCCITierIndicesData'
        },
        regions: {
            method: 'GetCCIRegionIndicesData'
        },
        city: {
            method: 'GetCCICityIndicesData'
        }
    },
    Demographics: {}
}
```

anything wrong?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question - it doesn't make a lot of sense. What do you mean by 'adding the array to the URL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `keyIndex` is evaluated only once when the `baseURL` string is created.

You could make `baseURL` a function instead...

```
baseURL:function() {
    return 'http://107.20.173.235/BlufinAPI/Service/ConsumerConfidenceIndex.svc/GetCCINationalIndicesData?InputJSON={"IndexID":"' + 
            this.keyIndex + 
            '","FromMonth":"10","FromYear":"2011","ToMonth":"3","ToYear":"2012"}';
}
```

Then call it like a function...

```
dataObject.Indices.subIndex.baseURL();
```

---

Although the original `keyIndex` was not a reference to the object property in the first place.

And this has nothing to do with jQuery.